# contract error while deploying to mainnet

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

[error while deploying to mainnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjVXO.png)
[running well on testnet & deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OHG.png)

I tried to deploy the contract on mainnet but got this error. network is polygon.
but while deploying at testnet it was deployed on testnet.If i click on send transaction then the transaction will failed.
& this error is related to contract storage.
"contract creation code storage out of gas"

Comment: Try switching network on metamask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have successfully deployed a contract to Mumbai testnet. Now, you are trying to deploy the same contract to Polygon(mainnet) but receive the error *"gas required exceeds allowance"*.

Usually, this error occurs if you attempt to execute a transaction with an insufficient amount of native coin used to pay the gas, in your case it's Matic on Polygon.

To fix this issue, you need to charge your wallet on Polygon mainnet with Matic to pay the current gas price.

Comment: i have enough 2 matics to deploy contract. though error is coming

Comment: & this error is related to contract storage.contract creation code storage out of gas","id":2238349044964316}

Comment: I understand, it still sounds like an insufficient Matic error...  Can you please share the full smart contract code?

Comment: ok share me your telegram id , slack or email id

Comment: I think it will be best to edit your question and add your smart contract code, this way also other people may assist in this issue.